# Manually created ServiceAccount in GCP belong to Project? Resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a service account which is not auto created. we created it. Now how do we check the scope of this serviceaccount?

Comment: [Cloud Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging/examples-service-accounts#auth-as-service-account) help you answer the questions "who did what, where, and when?" for your Google Cloud resources.

Comment: This [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-gcloud-manual) describes how to grant, change, and revoke access to a resource. You can allow [members and resources to impersonate](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) or act as, an Identity and Access Management (IAM) service account.

Comment: Edit your question. Service Accounts do not have `scopes`. You can attach roles to a service account. You can also assign a service account to a resource and attach roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account is an account, like a user account. The difference is the service account belong to a project (you have the project ID in the  @....). The user account is a Google account, managed by Google or by your administration.

Then, except where the account is attached, there is no other difference: you can grant roles and permissions on it. As a user account. When you have created it, if you grant no role, the service account has no permission, even on its host project.